# GCM Listener can't retrieve real value

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, listener

I have a GCM Listener, everything is ok, except that i have a parameter (key,value) in a GCM Message (Bundle data) and a specific key can't be retrieved with his get method and i have to "patch" (or re-try) the returned value, like this:

```
// this can't retrieve the value, 
// example: "id" in message is = 123, intValue gets 0 (default value for int)
int intValue = data.getInt("id"); 
if (intValue == 0) {
    // but this way can catch the int value, 
    // example: "id" in message is = 123, intValue gets 123;
    intValue = Integer.valueOf(data.getString("id"));
}
```

I have to "patch" the returned (or failed retrieved) value in the data,

why is this happening?
(key name it's the same in both cases, shouldn't be)

Comment: I dont undertand what you're trying to do, but just seeing that code, you cant compare a primitive type to null.

Comment: i had Integer == null cause i was testing, sorry i updated code.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. If getInt is returning the default value, if because there is no INT item inside the bundle with that name ("id"). Does the "patch" work? Can you retrieve it as a string?

Comment: the main problem is i can't get the id=123 value with data.getInt("id"); but i can get the value with data.getString("id");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the main problem is i can't get the id=123 value with
>   data.getInt("id"); but i can get the value with data.getString("id");
>   the rest of values and types are ok like getBoolean, get

Then you'll have to check how you're generating the JSON you send to the GCM servers. Probably you are sending the id attr. as a String (with the quotation Marks), that's why you only can read its value with getString()

Comment: the GCM Sender it's in Server (Another department) but what you say make sense. So i have to use the manual solution in my side :/ ... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The GCM bundle only contains a map of strings. That's why getInt("id") is returning 0.
You need to parse the values manually.
Just make sure you catch NumberFormatException and then set the variable to 0 in this case.

```
int intValue;

try{
    intValue = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("id"));
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
    intValue = 0;
}
```